# sequence generation without exponential notation in linux

Tags: linux, seq

Hi I am trying to generate a sequence of numbers using seq command

```
seq  830456481  831456481
```

result is below

```
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
```

However i would like to get my output as belwo in a different format with the exponent notation .

```
Expected output

830456481
830456482
830456483
......
```

How can i achieve it ?

Comment: That is.. very strange. What does `seq --version` output?

Comment: Prasanths-MacBook-Air:tmp kannan$ seq --version
seq: illegal option -- -
seq: illegal option -- v
seq: illegal option -- e
seq: illegal option -- r
usage: seq [-w] [-f format] [-s string] [-t string] [first [incr]] last

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My `seq` (v 8.32 on MacOS with brew) already prints just the numbers (e.g., 830456481) by default, so I'm just guessing here. [`man seq`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/seq) mentions a `-f` format argument. You could try

```
seq  -f "%f" 830456481 830456485
830456481.000000
830456482.000000
830456483.000000
830456484.000000
830456485.000000
```

Passing "%g" as a format gets me the scientific notation you see.

```
seq  -f "%g" 830456481 830456485
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
8.30456e+08
```

The format parameter is not well documented, and you'd have to know a bit about the C [`printf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) function to get it right. I can specify "%.0f" to get output without ".00000" as with plain "%f":

```
seq  -f "%.0f" 830456481 830456485
830456481
830456482
830456483
830456484
830456485
```